# polyglossia and Russian hyphenation

Tags: xetex, hyphenation, polyglossia

I try to set Russian hyphenation for polyglossia/xelatex (I use pandoc 1.15.2.1).

I've installed two packages:

```
$ tlmgr info hyphen-russian
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.asis.io/systems/texlive/tlnet
package:     hyphen-russian
category:    TLCore
shortdesc:   Russian hyphenation patterns.
longdesc:    Hyphenation patterns for Russian in T2A and UTF-8 encodings. For 8-bit engines, the 'ruhyphen' package provides a number of different pattern sets, as well as different (8-bit) encodings, that can be chosen at format-generation time.  The UTF-8 version only provides the default pattern set.  A mechanism similar to the one used for 8-bit patterns may be implemented in the future.
installed:   Yes
revision:    23085
sizes:       
relocatable: No
collection:  collection-langcyrillic 

$ tlmgr info ruhyphen
package:     ruhyphen
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Russian hyphenation.
longdesc:    A collection of Russian hyphenation patterns supporting a number of Cyrillic font encodings, including T2, UCY (Omega Unicode Cyrillic), LCY, LWN (OT2), and koi8-r.
installed:   Yes
revision:    21081
sizes:       run: 249k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.6
cat-date:    2012-06-04 13:41:04 +0200
cat-license: lppl
```

I have a book in Russian and English. But I see hyphenation for English words only, not for Russian ones. How can I fix it?

I use the last BasicTeX for OS X.

Comment: Without a minimal example of a document, it's really difficult to help.

Comment: I mean should I set hyphenation for Russian explicitly? I didn't do it for English, but hyphenation works perfectly...

Comment: I've read in Polyglossia package manual that this package `Loading the appropriate hyphenation patterns` automatically. But it loads the only hyphenation patterns for English, not for Russian.